# Understanding div and CSS

Tags: css, html

I would think if you have a div with css height:100% then any div's nested inside of that would only take up the space of its parent div. This doesn't seem to be the case.

I am trying to have a header and footer on the web page to my flash game. I do not want to have any vertical scrolling and the content should take up the entire page. I have a div format as follows

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="swfcontent"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

I make wrapper have 100% height, then I make header have 3% height, swfcontent 95% height and footer 2% height. This works but having a header that scales with browser size is undesirable. It will make my logo scale and be distorted.

What I would like to do is have the header and footer have a static pixel size of say 20 and 10px. Then the swf would take up all of the remaining space, i.e. 100%. However this makes the page grow and have vertical scaling.

How can a page be setup to have a header of 20px, footer of 10px and a swf that takes up all remaining space with no vertical scrolling. This of course has to still work if the browser is scaled.

Comment: If you don't want vertical scroll then you can use the CSS overflow property.

Comment: Getting rid of the scrollbar doesnt stop the content from still overflowing underneath the screen. It just makes it unaccessible now.

Answer (score 0):

By default a `<div>` is `position:static`, which does not establish a new positioned context. All widths, heights, and positions of children are not relative to the div itself, but its current positioned parent.

To cause your div to establish a new coordinate system set it to `position:relative` or `position:fixed` or `position:absolute`.

Comment: I have already tried combinations of all of those. Could you be more specific please? An example would help me a lot :)

Comment: Yes, an example would help a lot. Please provide your best attempt so far with full code.

Comment: `<div id="Container">
  <div id="Header"></div>
  <div id="flashContent">
  </div> 
  <div id="Footer"></div>
        </div> <!-- End Container -->``#Container
{
 height:100%;
 position:relative:
}

#Header
{
 width:100%;
 height:20px;
 background-color: #C0C0C0;
 position:relative;
 top:0;
}

#Footer
{
 width:100%;
 background-color:#C0C0C0;
 height:10px;
 position:relative;
 bottom:0;
}` Then on the embedswf I set width and height to 100%

Comment: This ends up giving me a vertical scroll bar by the size of the header+footer. It is making the swf 100% of the browser instead of 100% of the space in between the header and footer. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: https://zynga.com/play/cityville/?src=company&aff=games is a nice example of a static header and footer with a flash game in between the two. Their code is difficult to understand though. Do you know how they do it?

Comment: Code in comments is not very helpful. Try JSFiddle.net

Comment: Thanks for trying but no. The goal was to have the content in the center always take up the full empty space and never vertical scale. In your example if you add enough text it just overflows and vertical scales. This won't work with a flash movie as the center content.